# CRS for Ellipsoid Measurements

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3, ellipsoid

I noticed within the "Project Properties" there's an option for, Measurements --> Ellipsoid. What should this setting be configured to?

From what I read online, if this is set incorrectly, it can skew your measurements and provide inaccurate results.

Note: I'm currently using `EPSG:26917`. QGIS 3.14

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More information on your CRS can be found here: https://epsg.io/26917
There you can also see that `EPSG:26917` uses `Ellipsoid: GRS 1980` by default, and is a projected CRS, with UoM in meters.

GIS Stack Exchange tag description on `ellipsoid`:

> An ellipsoid is a closed quadric surface that is a three-dimensional
> analogue of an ellipse. In geodesy, a reference ellipsoid is a
> mathematically-defined surface that approximates the geoid, the truer
> figure of the Earth, or other planetary body.

So your project set-up should be good as long as your project is within the extent given on the website at the top of this post.